# Correct output for function that counts occurrences of each digit in a string

Tags: python, counting

I want the output of the code to be something like this if the user enters a string of numbers like let's say... 122033

```
Enter string of numbers: 122033
0 occurs 1 time
1 occurs 1 time
2 occurs 2 times
3 occurs 2 times


def count_digits(s):
    res = [0]*10
    for x in s:
        res[int(x)] += 1
    while 0 in res:
        res.remove(0)
    return res

def main():
    s=input("Enter string of numbers: ")

    print(count_digits(s))
main()
```

This is the program that I have so far. At it's current state, if a user enters something like 122033 the output is:
    [1,1,2,2]

Note: I cannot use collections for this.

Answer (score 2):

You're pretty close to a working solution, but removing all the 0-count entries changes the indices of your list. You already need to write some custom pretty printing code, so just leave the 0s in and skip elements where the count is 0. Maybe something like this:

```
def count_digits(s):
    res = [0]*10
    for x in s:
        res[int(x)] += 1
    return res

def print_counts(counts):
    for (index, count) in enumerate(counts):
        if count == 1:
            print("%d occurs %d time" % (index, count))
        elif count > 1:
            print("%d occurs %d times" % (index, count))

def main():
    s=input("Enter string of numbers: ")

    print_counts(count_digits(s))
```

Answer (score 2):

Without `collections.Counter`, here is a pretty short and efficient solution:

```
>>> def count_digits(inp):
...     for a,b in sorted((c, inp.count(c)) for c in set(inp)):
...         print("{} occurs {} times".format(a, b))
...
>>> mystr = input("Enter string of numbers: ")
Enter string of numbers: 122033
>>> count_digits(mystr)
0 occurs 1 times
1 occurs 1 times
2 occurs 2 times
3 occurs 2 times
>>>
```

As Peter DeGlopper notes in the comment below, this solution will work for any character set, not just digits.  If however you want it to only work with digits, all you need to do is make a slight modification to the for-loop line:

```
for a,b in sorted((c, inp.count(c)) for c in set(inp) if c.isdigit()):
```

Adding `if c.isdigit()` to the end of that will make it only capture digits.

Comment: Counters are great, but the OP specifically said "I cannot use collections for this."

Comment: Yea, I just saw that.  Fixed.

Comment: This has the advantage of working for any alphabet, not just digits.

Comment: Also, it is much, much faster if the input string is long. I'm surprised at how much so. 1000 repetitions of this over a million-element input string took 107 seconds on my desktop, compared to 1412 seconds for the list-based implementation. Built in methods win out over even a single traversal with a custom implementation.

Answer (score 0):

An approach that does not use counters:

```
d = {}

for i in somestring:
   if i not in d:
     d[i] = 1
   else:
     d[i] += 1
for k,v in d.iteritems():
   print('{0} occurs {1} times'.format(k,v))
```

Comment: A more concise expression is `d[i] = d.get(i, 0) + 1`.